# How to prevent SpriteKit overlay in SceneKit to get all key down events

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit

I have a SceneKit view that works very fine. its view controller gets and manages the key down events in an override of `keyDown(with event: NSEvent)`.

But, as soon as I add a SceneKit overlay like this:

```swift
let skScene             = MySKScene(fileNamed: "Level1.scnassets/3_overlay.sks")!
scnView.overlaySKScene  = skScene
skScene.isUserInteractionEnabled    = false
```

The SKScene gets all the key down events (`Level1.scnassets/3_overlay.sks` is just an empty scene).

Worse, I did trace the events like this:

```swift
class MySKScene: SKScene {
    public override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("I reach here !")
        print("  isUserInteractionEnabled: \(self.isUserInteractionEnabled)")
        
        func printResponderChain(indent: String, resp: NSResponder) {
            print(indent + "type: \(type(of: resp))")
            if let father = self.nextResponder {
                printResponderChain(indent: indent + "  ", resp: father)
            }
        }
        printResponderChain(indent: "", resp: self)
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
I reach here !
  isUserInteractionEnabled: false
type: MySKScene
```

So the SKScene tells me at the same time:

1. the `keyDown` method is called
2. `isUserInteractionEnabled` is false
3. the responder chain is only made of the SKScene itself

How to fully disable the SKScene ?

Comment: To be clear, you want the `overlaySKScene` to ignore every key down event?

Comment: Yes, I want all events (should that be key or mouse or...) to be managed by the view controller, just as when I don't have the overlay. Thanks.